# jQuery buttonset images

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, radio-button

Is it possible to have an image as a background using jQuery buttonset()?

I tried with this markup, but the design screws up:

```
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" />
    <label for="radio1" id="lbl1">
        <img src="images/red.png" />
    </label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked" />
    <label for="radio2">
        <img src="images/blue.png" />
    </label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" />
    <label for="radio3">
        <img src="images/orange.png" />
    </label>
```

[image]

I googled for plugins, but didn't find what I need.

Anyone tried this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/c3KmQ/

it's using jQueryUI buttonset, which are easily customisable :

```
$( "#radio" ).buttonset();
$($('.ui-button')[0]).addClass('bgcolor-red');
$($('.ui-button')[2]).addClass('bgcolor-black');
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Thanks, this looks like what I need but I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL " with the above.